# ошибка на строке 24

Tags: python

```
q = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100]
w = q[randint(0, len(q)-1)]
print(w)
w = q[randint(0, len(q)-1)]
print(w)
w = q[randint(0, len(q)-1)]
print(w)
w = q[randint(0, len(q)-1)]
print(w)
w = q[randint(0, len(q)-1)]
print(w)
w = q[randint(0, len(q)-1)]
print(w)
w = q[randint(0, len(q)-1)]
print(w)
w = q[randint(0, len(q)-1)]
print(w)
w = q[randint(0, len(q)-1)]
print(w)


w = [input(), input(), input(), input(), input()]
q = w[randint(0, len(q)-1)]
print(w)
```

Comment: `w[randint(0, len(q)-1)]` -> `w[randint(0, len(w)-1)]`.

Answer (score 1):

len(q)-оч большое, но список W имеет лишь пять элементов